If $\tau\subset\tau'$ and $(E,\tau)$ is normal, then $(E,\tau')$?

If the topological space $(E, \tau)$ is normal and $\tau\subset\tau'$; is it always true that $(E,\tau')$ is normal?

The matter here would be that as there more open sets in $\tau'$ than in $\tau$ so there'd be more closed sets in $(E,\tau')$ than in $(E,\tau)$; how could I guarantee that for disjoint closed sets (in $\tau'$), there'd be open neighbourhoods in $\tau'$? What could we say about $T_3$ property as well? I know that $T_1;T_2$ are preserved as their statements only involve open sets
EDIT: Should I consider the Sorgenfrey line and verify if it's normal or not?

The Sorgenfrey line is indeed normal, so it won't give you the counterexample you seek. The Sorgenfrey plane, however...

Let $\tau$ be the usual topology on $\mathbb R$,
$Z = {\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb N} \subset \mathbb R$.
It is easy to see that
$\tau^\prime = {U \cup (V \setminus Z): U, V \in \tau}$
is a topology on $\mathbb R$, in fact the coarsest topology, which is finer than $\tau$ and such that $Z$ is closed.
Moreover, $\tau^\prime$ is not even regular. (This is somehow the standard example of a $T_2$, nonregular topology.)

@Ulli, it's not regular as for $p= {0}$ and $Z$, every open neighbourhood of $0$ in \tau' contains an usual open neighborhood of $0$ that intersects non-trivially $Z$ ($0 \in cl_{\tau}(Z))$, so intersects every open neighborhood of $Z$?

Let $\epsilon > 0$. $]-\epsilon, \epsilon[ \setminus Z$ is an open neighborhood of $0$ in $\tau'$ that doesn't intersect $Z$, and that doesn't contain an usual open neighborhood of $0$. However, from the form of the open neighborhoods of $0$ in $\tau'$ and that $Z$ is a sequence that converges to $0$ in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ you will deduce that $0$ and $Z$ can't be separated by disjoint open sets.

@Almanzoris, so an open neighborhood of $0$ will contain $]-\epsilon,\epsilon[-Z$ for some $\epsilon >0$ and let $n$ be sufficiently large such that $|\frac{1}{n}|<\epsilon$, but now it's true that every open neighborhood of $Z$ should be an usual one, so, in particular, it'd be an open neighborhood of $\frac{1}{n}$ and as $ \frac{1}{n} \in cl_{\tau}(]-\epsilon,\epsilon[-Z)$, the intersection would be not empty?

Yeah, nice, that's it.

If you know that non-normal spaces exist at all, then let $(X, \tau')$ be one. Then you can choose $\tau = \{\emptyset, X\}$ and and you have $\tau \subset \tau', (X,\tau)$ is normal and you have a counterexample.
An example for a non-normal space is $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $\tau'=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$.
$\{b\}$ and $\{c\}$ are closed in $\tau'$, but each open superset of either one will have to also contain $a$, making $(X, \tau')$ non-normal.

This is an additional answer that provides some feedback.
As you have seen, just from knowing that $\tau$ is normal or regular, and that $\tau \subseteq \tau'$, you can't guarantee that each pair of disjoint closed sets of $\tau'$ that aren't in $\tau$ can be separated by disjoint open sets; and you can't guarantee that a point and a closed set of $\tau'$ that isn't in $\tau$ and that doesn't have the point can be separated by disjoint open sets neither, respectively.
Let $X$ be a set. The indiscrete topology is pseudometrizable, and therefore, it is perfectly normal (which is stronger than regular and normal). Every topology on $X$ is finer, or equal, than the indiscrete topology. However, supposing that $X$ has $3$ elements or more, and let $p \in X$, the particular point topology on $X$ induced by $p$ isn't even $R_0$ ($\{p\}$ is open, but it doesn't contain the closure of $p$, which is $X$), so it isn't regular (for this, it is enough for $X$ to have $2$ elements or more); and it is neither normal (each point distinct of $p$ is closed, there are $2$ or more points distinct of $p$, and every open set contains $p$).
Getting back to the Sorgenfrey line, this space is normal, in fact, it is $T_6$. But, as mentioned in the comments by CJ Dowd, the Sorgenfrey plane (the product topology of the Sorgenfrey line with itself) isn't normal. You can consider the closed and discrete subspace $L = \{(x, -x) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and then prove that $K = \{(x, -x) : x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\}$ and $L\setminus K$ are disjoint closed sets that can't be separated by disjoint open sets. For a reference, see the second item of the counterexample number 84 in Counterexamples in Topology.
The Sorgenfrey plane is $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$, as this property is productive. The example that Ulli has posted in the comments is easier to prove and it works as the counterexample that illustrates that a topology finer than a $T_6$ topology may not even be $T_3$. That topology refines the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but it isn't regular, because $Z$ and $0$ can't be separated by disjoint open sets (for the readers, see the comments in the question). Evidently, as this space is $T_1$, then it isn't normal neither.
Note: Let $X$ be a set, if a topology $\tau$ on $X$ is $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$ or functionally $T_2$ and there is a topology $\tau'$ on $X$ such that $\tau \subseteq \tau'$, then $\tau'$ is $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$ or functionally $T_2$, respectively. (These are two separation axioms stronger than $T_2$ ("$T_2 \Leftarrow T_{2\frac{1}{2}} \Leftarrow \text{Functionally } T_2$") that are also preserved by finer topologies.)
